# error in file uploading codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Below is the  code  for my  controller....

```
public function do_upload()
    {

        $config['upload_path']='./upload/';
        $config['allowed_types']='gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('image_file');
        if($this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))
        {
            $filedata = $this->upload->data();
            $filename = $filedata['raw_name'].$filedata['file_ext'];

            return $filename;
        }

    }
```

After this call this function where You want to make this upload...in controller

```
    if($_FILES)
                    {
                        $this->do_upload();
                    }
```

but file is not uploaded.......why?

Comment: You don't actually tell us what error you get

Comment: You also call $this->upload->do_upload('image_file'); twice

Comment: what error u got? show the value of `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: @JohnConde second time when i use $this->upload->do_upload('image_file'); it is  under if condition to check file is uploded or not......

Comment: Is your file is uploaded or not and if not pls show what error u got? pls be specific

Comment: @pradeep  obviously before making post i done all this type of check....!

Comment: @pradeep no error is displyed but file is neither  move to the desired folder nor in the database...

Comment: what is the name of your file input, can u show your form?

Comment: @pradeep                                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
<label>Profile Picture</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control required" id="image_file" name="image_file">
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Your `do_upload` method should be like this :*

```
public function do_upload() 
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
    $config['allowed_types']='gif|jpg|png';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))
    {
        $filename = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        echo  $filename;die;
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
        die;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** :

`set upload_max_filesize` in your php ini greater than 2MB,

if it is `wamp` just follow :

`click on wamp => php => php settings => upload_max_filesize`

Comment: code which i write in the intial is working but only for image less than 2 MB why ? since i not define size of image anywhere so i think it should be work for image greater than 2 MB also.......can u solve this issue

Comment: set `upload_max_filesize` in your `php ini` ,if it is wamp just follow : `click on wamp => php => php settings => upload_max_filesize`

Comment: thanks, i got it actually its size issue , i was trying to upload size greater than 2MB but in php configuration size was 2MB this is the reason due to which it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this line.

$config['upload_path']='./upload/';

$config['allowed_types']='gif|jpg|png';

---

### $this->upload->initialize($config);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if($this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))
{

```
    $filename = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    echo  $filename;die;
}
else
{
    print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
    die;
}
```